# Pass a variable as an argument inside its own with block

Tags: vba, reference, subroutine, with-statement, param

I am tweaking my outlook rule in VBA and accidentally / instinctively tried to pass a variable by referring to it as a dot inside a With block

In my case the var was CurrentItem, and one of my subroutines expects it in the param list. Normally you can shorthand refer to a var that's inside a With block by using a dot (e.g. With regEx .Global = True, .Pattern = "^.*$" End With).

Trying to pass a dot as an arg however didn't work.  I'm curious if there is such a shorthand to reference the var itself inside the With block? Here's the code example:

```
With CurrentItem
    If .Class = olMail Then
        sFromName = .SenderName
        sID = .Sender.ID
        ''dot arg that doesn't work:
        ''GetSMTP sFromName, sID, .
        GetSMTP sFromName, sID, CurrentItem 
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't refer to the current item in a `With` block. This is indeed the best you can get:

```
With CurrentItem
    If .Class = olMail Then
        GetSMTP .SenderName, .Sender.ID, CurrentItem 
    End If
End With
```